# Get data in php from a java jar

Tags: java, php, jar

I am trying to implement an application whose front end has been developed in pHp and the back end application processing is done using Java.

After the end of an event in the front end, I need to pass some values from the front end  i.e. pHp to the Java jar file(This will contain the application logic) and get the results back to the pHp layer.

Before implementing it on a working model, I wanted to run it with test data to assess how it actually works but will all the reference that I had from the Internet and other books, I haven't been able to figure out why it is not working.

So, I have a `testphp.jar` file which has following definition :

```
public class main {
    main()
    {

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args.length>0)
        {
            System.out.println(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No argument");
        }
    }
}
```

My pHp code runs on a xampp server . I am calling the jar using the following command based on the references that I took from the internet.

```
exec('java -jar testphp.jar $argument', $output);
```

I expect the output i.e. the standard output i.e. `System.out.print()` to get in the `$output`, but I am getting an empty array every time.

I do not understand where am I going wrong.

I would be glad if some one could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the argument is actually replaced by the real value.

Try generating the string outside the exec. Something like:

`$param = "java ....... $argument";`

Note that the double quotes are relevant.